# minimax algorithm understanding

Tags: python, minimax

I'm having a hard time understanding the recursive part of the minimax Algorithm.

```
def minimax(state, depth, player):
    if player == MAX:
        best = [-1, -1, -infinity]
    else:
        best = [-1, -1, +infinity]

    if depth == 0 or game_over(state):
        score = evaluate(state)
        return [-1, -1, score]

    for cell in empty_cells(state):
        x, y = cell[0], cell[1]
        state[x][y] = player
        score = minimax(state, depth - 1, -player)
        state[x][y] = 0
        score[0], score[1] = x, y

        if player == MAX:
            if score[2] > best[2]:
                best = score
        else:
            if score[2] < best[2]:
                best = score

    return best
```

for example this code. when the function calls itself  inside the loop, the loop keeps going to  `state[x][y] = 0` ? what's stooping the function? or what actions the recursive part of the function does?
tnx

Comment: As for what "stops the function", is the `depth - 1` that is passed along in the recursive call. The function stops evaluating when it sees `depth == 0` has been reached (among other end-case scenarios).

Comment: After you come back from your call to `minimax` the code continues with the next line of code which is `state[x][y] = 0`. You leave the function when the code reaches one of the `return` statements.

Answer (score 2):

You have recursive function, that is a function that calls itself with (hopefully) different arguments. The question is: how do we prove that such a function ever stops? The generic proof is a proof by induction: let `n` be an argument of the function `f`. If you can show that:

- `f(0)` is defined
- recursive calls inside `f(n)` are always of type `f(k)` where `0 <= k < n`

You have a proof by induction (strong version) that `f(n)` is defined for every `n >= 0`.

In your function, `depth` is a good candidate for `n`. But `len(empty_cells(state))` too. Look at the two statements that surround the recursive call:

```
state[x][y] = player
...
state[x][y] = 0
```

This is a common technique: you update the state before the call, and restore the state after the call (assumption: a cell `(x, y)` is empty if `state[x][y] == 0`). Hence, the number of empty cells of the recursive call is lower than the current number of empty cells.

And you might have a `game_over` state.

Without additional information, it is impossible to say what will stop the recursive calls: `depth` reaches `0`, there's a `game_over` or there are no empty cells left.

Note that `depth` might be negative at the beginning, `game_over` might never occur, but it is certain that the function will stop when the number of empty cells is `0` (if it has not stopped before).

---

I think you're having a hard time understanding this piece of code because the `score` variable is sometimes a number, sometimes a 3 elements list (and should probably be a tuple in this case).
Furthermore, the stop condition could be at the beginning of the function.

This version should be clearer because it hides the behavior variations caused by `+/-player`:

```
def minimax(state, depth, player):
    if depth == 0 or game_over(state):
        score = evaluate(state)
        return [-1, -1, score]

    best = [-1, -1, initial_score(player)]
    for x, y in empty_cells(state):
        state[x][y] = player # fill this cell
        _, _, score = minimax(state, depth - 1, -player) # extract the score
        cur = [x, y, score]
        state[x][y] = 0 # restore state

        if is_better(player, cur, best):
            best = cur

    return best

def initial_score(player):
    if player == MAX:
        return -infinity
    else 
        return +infinity

def is_better(player, first, second):
    if player == MAX:
        return first[2] > second[2]
    else:
        return first[2] < second[2]
```

Much could be rewritten, but we're not https://codereview.stackexchange.com...